# Crash Core Plot library

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-plot

I am using core plot library Release 2.0 downloaded from https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases in MAC application to generate the bar graphs. When i install application on OSX 10.8 and 10.7 application crashes. It works well above 10.8.3.  The linker flags is  -ObjC and -all_load is already set in build settings.

I am getting below issue in logs. Can any one please look the issue and help me to resolve.

```
-[NSColorSpaceColor CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff4caa6e0c0
-[NSColorSpaceColor CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff4caa6e0c0

2016-05-10 11:39:17.072 [375:807] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f781d16 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff96a329ea objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f80ccfe -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f76f073 ___forwarding___ + 371
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f76ee88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   CorePlot                            0x0000000101720cbf +[CPTTextStyle(CPTPlatformSpecificTextStyleExtensions) textStyleWithAttributes:] + 191
    6   CorePlot                            0x000000010170e3ee -[CPTTextLayer initWithAttributedText:] + 62
    7   CorePlot                            0x00000001017083b8 -[CPTAxis updateAxisLabelsAtLocations:inRange:useMajorAxisLabels:] + 1880
    8   CorePlot                            0x00000001017089cc -[CPTAxis relabel] + 700
    9   CorePlot                            0x000000010170985a -[CPTAxis layoutSublayers] + 42
    10  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff9378e9aa _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 312
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff9378deec _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 308
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff9378dc74 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 274
    13  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff9378d275 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 63
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f741f37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f741e96 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 374
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f7168e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 258
    17  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff951b6c57 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
    18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff951be33d ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
    19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff951be1ca BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff903b73e9 _DPSNextEvent + 659
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff903b6cf0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff903b368d -[NSApplication run] + 456
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff90630cfb NSApplicationMain + 860
    )
```

Comment: What axis labeling policy are you using? Are you using a custom `labelFormatter` that returns attributed text?

Comment: I am using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic and not using any custom labelFormatter.

Comment: According to Apple's docs, the `CGColor` method is available on 10.8 and later. What version of Core Plot are you using? Version 2.1 has a deployment target of 10.8. Older versions back to at least 1.6 contain a check that should prevent the call to the `CGColor` method when it is not available.